# CSS: how to draw white (main) frame upward?

Tags: html, css

I'm not a very experienced css user and so I have a question about an existing HTML + CSS template. I want to use this template to make a website: http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page187/life-in-color#shout

I want to personalize this template and I have already tried hours to draw the white frame upwards, so that the header (logo and top menu) into the white frame. ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA9sU.png)) I can't fix it myself.

Is this possible, so yes, how?

Many thanks in advance,
T. Hægh

Comment: css file: http://www.free-css.com/assets/files/free-css-templates/preview/page187/life-in-color/css/style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `<header>` in to the `.main` class

Comment: Thank you sir, I was thinking to difficult.